# Type Error no implicit conversion of String into Integer in index.json.jbuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, jbuilder

I am working with Rails1.4.1 and jbuilder

In `index.json.jbuilder` have the code,

```
if @event_templates.count == 0
    json.message "Not found"
end
```

But Its givining error as,

```
Type Error no implicit conversion of String into Integer
```

If i give simple `json.message 'Not found'` in index page,
Giving same error!!!

Any wrong i am doing here!!!

But the same code working fine in `show.json.jbuilder`

```
json.message "Not found"
```

Comment: it is full `index.json.jbuilder` ? Post please `show.json.jbuilder`

Comment: same - json.message "Not found"

Comment: Solved, committed some small mistake. Cheers!!!